# Difference between prompting and cueing?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Is there any difference between prompting and cueing in usage and meaning ?

Imagine you are a speech therapist and this is a part of your report of your case who has difficulty in speech

> Yasser can point to pictures of prepositions ‘in’, ‘on’ and ‘under’ with visual cueing. He identifies all high frequency verbs without any support. He is now able to follow two step commands without prompting however he still requires verbal and visual cueing.

So I assume that when it is said that " he is able to follow two step commands without prompting " so he does not need cueing either verbal or visual.

Comment: Yes, depending on context. Do you have a particular context in mind?

Comment: Imagine you are a speech therapist and this is a part of your report of your case who has difficulty in speech " Yasser can point to pictures of prepositions ‘in’, ‘on’ and ‘under’ with visual cueing. He identifies all high frequency verbs without any support. He is now able to follow two step commands without prompting however he still requires verbal and visual cueing." Cueing and prompting both are indicating that s/he needs some direction and guides so I assume that

Comment: So I assume that when it is said that " he is able to follow two step commands without prompting " so he does not need cueing either verbal or visual

Comment: Thanks for providing more context - I have retracted my close vote. In the future, you may want to [edit] your question to include it (as @NathanTuggy did for you) instead of adding comments. Comments do not "bump" your question, so its easy for us to miss the changes you've made. When your question is edited, people can change their votes on it also. If you don't edit the question, people can't change their votes.

Comment: Like in most technical contexts, a word can have a specific meaning, which is not necessarily the same as the meaning used by people outside the field. A quick search for *speech therapy prompting cueing* gave me this page, https://www.facebook.com/TheSLPstudent/posts/296813460414101: "Cues are signals you give before the client responds (don't forget your /s/ sound, or remember to pull your tongue back). Prompts are given during the client's response or an attempt (the client does to say dame for same and you give them a tactile prompt to make the /s/ correctly)."

Answer (score 0):

I think prompting is more of guiding someone to doing or saying what you want them to do or say by asking questions etc., while cueing is like signalling someone else to do something. There's quite a big difference.

Comment: Hi, Adele, welcome to ELL!  A suggestion: answers are usually more useful to the questioner if you can provide some references, definitions, or examples of usage, rather than just opinion.

Comment: I have not gotten my answer yet